# limit of $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{(n+2)}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k}{(k+3)}$ without using any convergence tests.

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I calculate the limit of $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{(n+2)}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k}{(k+3)}$ without using any knowledge of convergence tests.

It is quite easy to show that the $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k}{(k+3)}$ does not converge, using the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{k}{(k+3)}=1$. Therefore $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k}{(k+3)}=\infty$, and so it can be concluded that  $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{(n+2)}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k}{(k+3)}=\infty$.

This exercise was given when the student studied only the limits of series (first semester).

I assume there are algebraic manipulations on the infinite series that would help solve the problem without using convergence tests, but I could not manage to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $n\geq 3$. Then,
\begin{align}
\frac{n}{n+2}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k}{k+3}&\geq\frac{n}{n+2}\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{k}{k+3}\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{n-3}{2}.
\end{align}
What happens as $n\to\infty$? Ok we can clean up the algebra even more. For example if $n\geq 15$, then $\frac{n-3}{4}\geq \frac{n}{5}$, so $\frac{n}{n+2}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k}{k+3} \geq\frac{n}{5}$. Now it should be super clear, and we can even write a formal proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=\frac{n}{(n+2)}$, $b_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k}{(k+3)}$.

Since $a_n\to1\neq0$, $a_nb_n$ converges if and only if $b_n$ converges. But $b_n$ diverges since

$$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k}{(k+3)}\ne0$$

therefore, $a_nb_n$ diverges.

Comment: OP wants to avoid this argument.

Comment: The OP wants to solve it without using comparison test or other advanced test. It didn't say avoid to use this method. @Abezhiko